# Exposing osgi service as JAX-RS using apache cxf

Tags: osgi, cxf, jax-rs, ipojo

Can somebody provide me a simple example to expose a Restful service using apache cxf in an osgi bundle deployed on apache felix. We do not have the option to use Apache Karaf or any other application server.
Also , we plan to use iPojo for dependency injection.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately installing CXF in plain apache felix is not very easy. Your best bet is to install on apache karaf first and get the list of required bundles from there.

You can find an example for cxf and rest with Apache Karaf [here](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/tree/master/cxf/personservice-rest).

As you migrate you might need to tune the system package exports of felix to exclude the packages CXF wants to install as bundles.

I found something that may further help you. Type these commands in karaf 3.0.3:

```
feature:repo-add cxf 3.0.4
kar:create cxf-3.0.4 cxf-jaxrs
```

This will create a kar file in data/kar that contains the cxf feature file as well as all the jars (from the cxf feature). It allows you to specify which cxf features you need and quickly gather the required bundles. It will still be some work to make it work in felix but at least it helps a bit on the way.